# Pandas: Change values in multiple columns according to boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas

This should be a simple thing to do but somehow I can't wrap my head around all the different ways of selecting and masking things in Pandas yet.

So for a big dataframe (read in from a csv file) I want to change the values of a list of columns according to some boolean condition (tested on the same selected columns).

I tried something like this already, which doesn't work because of a mismatch of dimensions:

```
df.loc[df[my_cols]>0, my_cols] = 1
```

This also doesn't work (because I'm trying to change values in the wrong columns I think):

```
df[df[my_cols]>0] = 1
```

And this doesn't work because I'm only changing a copy of the dataframe:

```
df[my_cols][df[my_cols]>0] = 1
```

Here is the output of `df.info`:

```
Int64Index: 186171 entries, 0 to 186170
Columns: 737 entries, id to 733:zorg
dtypes: float64(734), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 1.0+ GB
```

Can some more advanced Pandas user help? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry can you post code to demonstrate how it doesn't work, normally this should work: `df[df[my_cols] >0] = 1` your first attempt won't work as you're returning a multidimentionsal array and trying to index using this

Comment: what is my_cols, a list or a pandas.index?

Comment: @EdChum: I got this error message: "TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value". I'm not sure how to interpret this, though.

Comment: @lib: it's a normal list with column names.

Comment: It means that your columns are mixed dtypes, are some ints or strings rather than float? Can you post output from `df.info()`

Comment: Yes, but the columns that I'm trying to change should all be floats. `dtypes: float64(734), int64(1), object(2)`

Comment: maybe do you have to use np.any()  or np.all()  in your condition? it seems that your condition is about elements but you will work on columns

Answer (score 3):

So here is how I finally got the desired result, but I feel there must be a more pandas-ish solution for this task.

```
for col in my_cols:
    df.loc[df[col]>0, col] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `pandas.DataFrame.where`

> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
>   are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.

In your case this would become:

```
df[my_cols] = df[my_cols].where(~(df[my_cols]>0),other=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure there is a more elegant way, but this should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(3,4)), columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
mycols =['a','b']
cols_tochange = df.columns[df[mycols].all()>1]
df.loc[:,cols_tochange]  = 1
```

Note the use of `all()`, for getting the condition on the whole column

Comment: I don't think that that is what I want though. I don't want to check if the condition is true for all values in the column, but I want to check it for each individual value in the column and change (or not change) the value accordingly.

Comment: ah ok...yes, this would change all the column